# Bronze badge number not visible on flagging page

Tags: bug, design

When I go to to my flagging page I see this:

[image: Number of bronze flags not visible]

The number of bronze flags is not visible (unless I mouse over, then I see the number in a tool tip).

**Update:** I've only seen this in *Google Chrome* (Version 31.0.1650.57) on a *Windows 7* system. On the same Windows system, I tested it in Internet Explorer and Firefox where the issue did not occur. Also tested on an iPad with Safari - again, not seen. The exact link is, in my case:

> https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/62

but that last number will depend on your ID - I suspect only SE employees and myself can view that link (replace the number with yours to get your own flag summary page).

Comment: They are going to want system information to diagnosis this. For it to actually be a bug it needs to be reproducible. They will need your OS, Browser name and version number, and the exact page (link) that you see this (I don't know what the flagging page is).

Comment: @fredsbend: thanks for the tip - now I know the problem is much more localised than I thought. FWIW - yours is: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/3961 (which I can't read, btw!).

Comment: This also affects other areas where the user card is displayed. See also: [Number of bronze badges partially visible](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3317)